# Google Play Console still reviewing my app for almost 3 weeks

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play-console

I developed an Ionic-Angular Project that targets IOS and Android devices, when I uploaded the app to Apple Store it took less than 24 hours to accept the application. I uploaded the app to Google Play Console the same day, and I'm still waiting...

I did not use internal testing or closed testing because I have my own testing team, and I did a full roll-out for production, but it took 3 weeks, and the app still 'In Review'...

this is my first time uploading an app to Google Play, I feel something is missing.

What to do in this case? I really need to upload the app faster.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.